# flutter pub get error when i edit my pubspec.yaml file

Tags: flutter

I have an error when i try to add a new plugin in my `pubspec.yaml`

i add the plugin : `easy_localization: ^3.0.0`

And i have this error message :

```
Because flutter_launcher_icons >=0.7.0 <0.9.0 depends on args ^1.5.0 and easy_localization >=3.0.0-nullsafety depends on args ^2.0.0, flutter_launcher_icons >=0.7.0 <0.9.0 is incompatible with easy_localization >=3.0.0-nullsafety.
So, because gameapp depends on both easy_localization ^3.0.0 and flutter_launcher_icons ^0.8.0, version solving failed.
pub get failed (1; So, because gameapp depends on both easy_localization ^3.0.0 and flutter_launcher_icons ^0.8.0, version solving failed.)
```

Answer (score 1):

Could you try adding,

```
 flutter_launcher_icons: ^0.9.0 
 args: ^2.0.0 
 easy_localization: ^3.0.0-nullsafety
```

to your `pubspec.yaml` and try saving it again to reload the packages?

Comment: @axis-medias doesn't work means, does the pubspec still gives you an error or some feature is not working in the program? I have faced similar issues with vs code. When I get the packages installed, restarting vs code usually does the trick.

Comment: When i add the 3 lines over i have new error messages :

Answer (score 1):

The problem is: The library version you want to use is newer than Flutter, and there are two solutions
1: Go to the library website and click on the version and install an old library, for example (easy_localization: ^ 2.3.3)
2: Install the latest version of Flutter. Flutter2

Comment: i have installed a new version of fluter and dart but problem is exactly the same and when i try to install old version of easy_localization it doesn't work too